# IPTable SNAT rule is not evaluated

Tags: iptables, nat

I am trying to SNAT and DNAT a flow with IPTables and I am struggling with SNAT.
The rule does not seem to be evaluated and I don't know why.

Here are the rules:

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 117 packets, 5372 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1        2   120 DNAT       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            xx.xx.xx.xx         to:99.99.99.1

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 6 packets, 396 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1        0     0 SNAT       all  --  *      *       192.198.0.0/24       0.0.0.0/0            to:192.168.4.40
```

Also, `net.ipv4.ip_forward` is set to `1`.

When I do a tcpdump to see what's happening, I see that destination IP is NATed but not the source IP:

```
15:16:49.994739 IP 192.168.0.4.55149 > xx.xx.xx.xx.443: Flags [S], seq 1558061817, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 2666551254 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
15:16:49.994797 IP 192.168.0.4.55149 > 99.99.99.1.443: Flags [S], seq 1558061817, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 2666551254 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
```

Am I missing something ?

Comment: Is `192.198.0.0` in your SNAT rule a typo? Judging by the tcpdump it looks like maybe it should be `192.168.0.0`?

Comment: Oh my god, I'm ashamed. I literally spent 1 hour troubleshooting... Thanks Xavier !

Comment: No worries! We've ALL done something like that.  Sometimes it just takes a fresh set of eyes looking at it.